# Google CSE "Search Term(s)" to be saved in own way?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Since i'm using Google CSE, the main idea is to show the "***Top Search Terms***" under the CSE Search box. But in the CSE panel, Google is saying:

> No queries were sufficiently popular to be listed

So anyway (i don't want to wait it to be sufficient enough and) .. i want to implement it on my own.

- What is the best **way to capture the `submit`** of the search string (to Google) ?

Or

- What is the best way to **capture the `returning results`** (back from Google) so i can assume the `Search Term` has been used. So i can mark/save the current search term.

.

As a reference, this is all i've done so far:

```
<!-- Goolge CSE -->
<script language="JavaScript">
  (function() {
    var cx = 'xxxx3941849086xxxxx:xxxxmtk5xxxxxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<body>
    <!-- GCSE Search Box -->
    <div class="global-search">
        <gcse:searchbox-only  linktarget="http://www.example.com/search" queryParameterName="query"></gcse:searchbox-only>
    </div>
    <!-- GCSE Result Div -->
    <div id="googlecse-result">
        <gcse:search linktarget="_parent" queryParameterName="query"></gcse:search>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement something by yourself which Google does already for you?

Comment: So means, we can not do anything by ourselves then? Or.. is there no way we can do it?

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to track your user's activity, [Google Analytics](http://www.google.at/intl/en/analytics/) might be the better tool.

Comment: No. I'm not asking about the usage of Google Tools anymore. My question was `how to capture the submission (or) returning of GCSE query`. (This is because everybody has their own specific scenarios.)

Answer (score 1):

I find the value of the search term here and save in my own db:

```
google.search.cse.element.getElement('standard0').getInputQuery()
```

I wouldn't advise you hardcoding 'standard0'.

If you give your gcse elements a name using `gname="SomeName"` then you can use this as a reference.

```
google.search.cse.element.getElement('SomeName').getInputQuery()
```